# Lower bounds of laplace transform of characteristic functions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, laplace-transform, convolution, characteristic-functions

I have the following integral:
\begin{equation}
f(\mu) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu t}\varphi_X(t)dt
\end{equation}
where $\varphi_X(t)$ is the characteristic function of some undetermined probability distribution and $\mu$ is some complex variable with strictly positive real part $\mu_r>0$.

It is easy enough to prove that this function is bounded above, $|f(\mu)| \le \frac{1}{\mu_r}$.

However, numerics suggest that for 'nice' distributions (symmetric, and non-increasing on $[0,\infty)$), the integral is bounded below by $|f(\mu_r)|\le|f(\mu)|$.

**So my questions are:**

> 1) Are there established results on finding lower bounds of the Laplace transform of a characteristic function. (My trawling of google scholar and the like haven't produced anything. It seems like such an elementary problem that surely someone has considered it before.)
>
> 2) If not what general techniques are used to look for lower bounds on integrals such as this?

Background:

The integral comes from investigating how non-identical frequency distribution of linear oscillators a particular collective behavior problem. It turns out that the solutions of these problems can be described in terms of the solutions \begin{equation}
f(\mu) = \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{\mu - \mathrm{i} X}\right)
\end{equation}
where is $X$ set of frequencies. If we consider the real part only, we can relate this to the convolution of a Cauchy distribution (with median $\mu_i$ and spread $\mu_r$) with the distribution of frequencies. Treating it as a convolution allows us to use Fourier transforms to reformulate the integral as above, which seemed to me a easier (or at least seemingly more natural) problem.

This has occurred before in such problems and has been treated asymptotically for strictly real $\mu$ [1] and commented on for complex $\mu$ (appendix [2]). Due to the parameter regions we are interested in (around $\Re{\mu} =1$) the approximations made previously no longer hold.

Many Thanks, Pete.

References:

[1] - RE. Mirollo, SH Strogatz. *Amplitude Death in Limit Cycle Oscillators*. http://www.springerlink.com/index/ln051rp502550471.pdf

[2] - PC. Matthews, RE. Mirollo, SH Strogatz. *Dynamics of a large system of coupled nonlinear oscillators*. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016727899190129W

Comment: [Watson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson's_lemma) may give you some insight.

Comment: The link to Mirollo & Strogatz's paper at `springerlink.com` is broken, but it can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF01013676](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01013676).

Answer (score 0):

One could start from the formula
$$
f(\mu)=\mathbb E\left(\frac1{\mu-\mathrm iX}\right).
$$
If $\mu=\mu_r+\mathrm i\nu$, this is also
$$
f(\mu)=\mathbb E\left(\frac{\mu_r+\mathrm i(X-\nu)}{\mu_r^2+(\nu-X)^2}\right).
$$

Comment: Actually Did, that is where the question is derived from.

Comment: Actually you could have mentioned it in the question.